# Else condition seems not working in my JSP

Tags: java, jsp, if-statement

I have following code in one of my JSPs.

```
<% if(rsmatches!=null){%>
              <table>
                  <tr>
                      <td class="captions">Match</td>
                      <td>

                          <select>
                              <%

                               while(rsmatches.next()){ 
                                %>
                                <option value="<%out.print(rsmatches.getString("matchid"));%>"><%out.print(rsmatches.getString("matchid"));%> - <%out.print(rsmatches.getString("team1name"));%> vs <%out.print(rsmatches.getString("team2name"));%></option>
                                <%}%>
                          </select>
                      </td>
                  </tr>
              </table>

              <%} else{%>
              <h1>No Result</h1>
              <%}%>
```

So rsmatches is the resultset and when it is not null it gives the output as I expected, but when the Resultset has no results, Instead of showing

## No Result

, It shows the dropdown with no values in it. Where did I do the mistake?

Comment: Don't iterate over the `ResultSet` in JSP? and don't use scriptlets.

Comment: Are you sure rsmatches is null and not just an empty list?

Comment: @DilukshanMahendra JSP should just have presentation part. Database related task should be done in some backend Java classes. Also, Scriplets are dead almost a decade ago. Use JSTL tag libraries and EL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you tried this

```
<% if(rsmatches!=null && rsmatches.next()){%>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="captions">Match</td>
        <td>

        <select>
        <%

            do{ //Change to do while since result set is already pointing to the first row coz of the statement in if loop
        %>
                <option value="<%out.print(rsmatches.getString("matchid"));%>"><%out.print(rsmatches.getString("matchid"));%> - <%out.print(rsmatches.getString("team1name"));%> vs <%out.print(rsmatches.getString("team2name"));%></option>
            <%} while(rsmatches.next()) ;%>
        </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<%} else{%>
<h1>No Result</h1>
<%}%>
```

Comment: But as others have mentioned, it is always better to have only the presentation in the JSP and have all the database activities in a DAO layer

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<% if( rsmatches != null && rsmatches.size() > 0 ) { %>
```

Comment: Oops,there was no attribute as .size()

Comment: What is the class of rsmatches?

Comment: It is a sql ResultSet

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like rsmatches is empty (instantiated) not null which would explain why the else does not fire.

Comment: Well thx to the fine folks of SO, you have options.  The quickest would be sandy.sk's which chks for null and 'has rows or data'.  Depending on your experience also chk out CuriousMinds offering.  Your code would be nearly the same but you would be inspecting a collection and not the result set itself.  Separating this into another layer makes your code scalable and 'less coupled'.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it in wrong way. Ideally, you shouldn't have database related code inside, the JSP that shows the poor design of the application and violation of application layers.

Now to answer your question, ResultSet will never be null, even if there is no record fetched using query. Ideally, you should handle this scenario using

1. Read resultset in some class (preferably [DAO](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/dataaccessobject-138824.html)) and then build a collection. Later pass this collection to JSP to display data.
2. Along with checking null, fire resultSet.next() method to determine if next record exists. Later instead of using while loop use Do... while loop.